# Index of a stationary point of constrained optimization

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization

For an unconstrained optimization problem with objective function $F(x,y,z)$ the index of a stationary point is well-defined:
If $(x^*, y^*, z^*)$ is a point where the gradient of $F(x,y,z)$ vanishes, then $(x^*,y^*,z^*)$ is a stationary point of $F(x,y,z)$ and its index is the number of negative eigenvalues of the hessian matrix of $F(x,y,z)$ with respect to $x$, $y$ and $z$.

However, if $F(x,y,z)$ is then subject to some other nonlinear constraint $g(x,y,z) = 0$, then how is the index of the stationary point is defined in this case? I would think that the [bordered hessian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix#Bordered_Hessian) in place of the hessian and then the number of negative eigenvalues of the bordered hessian at a stationary point is the index of the stationary point. But I do not see any reference which clearly states this definition. In the wiki article, as well as [this one](http://www.math.northwestern.edu/~clark/285/2006-07/handouts/lagrange-2deriv.pdf), it only gives a condition for a stationary point not being a minimum nor a maximum. But they do not clearly define the index of such a stationary point. Is there any reference where I could find a precise definition?

Comment: why is it idiot to consider $\tilde{F}(x,y,z,\lambda) = F(x,y,z) + \lambda^T g(x,y,z)$ ?

Comment: @Smilia, it is not! Then, I am interested in knowing the definition of the index of a stationary point of \tilde{F}.